# Не работает :focus для input

Tags: html, css

Не работает `input:focus`

```
<div class="basket-data__input">
<div class="cabinet-data__text basket-data-text">Ваше имя</div> <input
class="basket-data-input" type="text" tabindex="0" placeholder="Ваше имя*">
</div>
<div class="basket-data__input">
<div class="cabinet-data__text basket-data-text">Ваше имя</div><input tabindex="1"
type="text" placeholder="Номер телефона*">
</div>
<div class="basket-data__input">
<div class="cabinet-data__text basket-data-text">Ваше имя</div><input tabindex="2"
type="text" placeholder="Электронная почта*"></div>
```

```
.basket-data__input {
   position: relative;
}
.basket-data-input:focus .basket-data-text {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
}
.basket-data-text {
   visibility: hidden;
   transition: 0.3s;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Пробовал через `+` тоже не работает, может кто знает в чем дело?

Comment: Селектор `.basket-data-input:focus .basket-data-text` означает, что внутри элемента с классом `basket-data-input` должен быть элемент с классом `basket-data-text`. Но у вас `basket-data-input` является элементом input, а внутри инпутов никогда не бывает вложенных элементов, поэтому этот селектор ничего не будет делать

Comment: Благодарю, но как в таком случае мне поступить, задача проявление текста при фокусе инпута.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить фокус элемента .basket-data-input, но это элемент div, а не input. Подскажите подробнее, какого эффекта Вы хотите добиться. Советую почитать про тег <label>, в Вашем случае нужно использовать его.

Comment: @NDMX .basket-data-input это на самом деле input, а не div (я тоже попался)

Comment: @andreymal да, это жёстко. Вот уж как путает такой нейминг.

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно заметил @andreymal в комментариях,

> селектор `.basket-data-input:focus .basket-data-text` означает, что
> внутри элемента с классом basket-data-input должен быть элемент с
> классом `basket-data-text`.

Вы пробовали использовать селектор `+`, но он тоже не работает, потому что выбирает элемент соседний, который следует после первого. (http://htmlbook.ru/css/selector/adjacent)

Для того, чтобы селектор `+` в нашем случае заработал, необходимо поменять элементы местами в html:

```
  <input id="name" class="basket-data-input" type="text" tabindex="0" placeholder="Ваше имя*">
  <label class="cabinet-data__text basket-data-text" for="name">Ваше имя</label>
```

А стилями уже подвинем на нужное место. Например это можно следать так:

```css
.basket-data__input {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.basket-data-input:focus+.basket-data-text {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.basket-data-text {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="basket-data__input">
  <input id="name" class="basket-data-input" type="text" tabindex="0" placeholder="Ваше имя*">
  <label class="cabinet-data__text basket-data-text" for="name">Ваше имя</label>
</div>
```

Ещё советую почитать про тег `<label>`, он как раз нужен для добавления подписей к элементам таблиц:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label